# JSF2 Form is not rendered with JavaScript function to disable all the form elements

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I want to disable all the elements in the form main and render form create on Add New button but i facing some problem as :On clicking on Add New Button the JS function is called but the form is disabled for a while and as well as the form create is not rendered.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function enableDisable(){
 alert("Enable Disable");
 var f = document.getElementById('main');
 var len=f.elements.length;
 for(x=0;len>x;x++) {
  f.elements[x].disabled=true;
 }
}
```

On clicking on Add New Button the JS function is called but the form is disabled for a while and as well as the form create is not rendered.

```
<h:commandButton onclick="enableDisable()" value="Add new" action="#{cars.resetCreate}"  render="create" >

</h:commandButton>
```

Comment: please edit your question and make this part understandable `I want to disable all the elements in the form main and render form create on Add New button but i facing ...` aswell as remaining question.Do highlights the ids , names of button and methods please.question like this is so terrifying

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is no `render` in `<h:commandButton>`.It is `rendered` which is boolean which takes `true` or `false`.JSF `commandButton` and `commandLink` are not in built with ajax like `<p:commandButton>` which is primefaces component.And the attribute `render` only applies to `<f:ajax>` . So, in your case If you want to get the `create` form you have to do something like this,

```
<h:commandButton onclick="enableDisable()" value="Add new" action="#{cars.resetCreate}">
    <f:ajax execute="@this" render="create">
</h:commandButton>
```